# How to get the records based on between two years

Tags: mysql

I am saving the reporting date as date format (ex 2017-04-05) now I want the records only between two years based on reporting date, I am giving the from year and two year as 2016 and 2017

### See My table structure

### report_id | report_date |  user_id | amount

### 1    | 2015-11-12  |   12    | 5000

### 2    | 2016-12-01  |   17    | 5000

### 3    | 2017-01-12  |  21    | 5000

### 4    | 2017-02-12  |  07    | 5000

The above table is my table structure

Now I want to get the records where report_date between year 2016 and 2017, I will not give complete date only I will give the year.

Comment: You can literally copy & paste your title into google and find an answer. That's just shamefull to be honest

Comment: May be i was not clear,now i have explained it please check it

Comment: You're right it wasn't the same as the other one, though there's probably a  question on here that's an exact duplicate. I'd recommend next time you first google your question before asking for help here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [YEAR()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php) to get just the year of a date, then you can search between years like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE YEAR(report_date) BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016;
```

Comment: If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider accepting it as the correct answer for others that might stumble upon the same issue